# Unable to find a way to customize the spinner and clearButton in asyncTypeHead in react-bootstrap-typehead <AsyncTypehead>

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

Spinner refers to the spinner that appears on the input on the right corner when isLoading = {true}.
clearButton refers to the clearButton to clear data in input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize those items by passing your own components via the typeahead's child render prop:

```
<Typeahead ... >
  {({ onClear, selected }) => (
    <div className="rbt-aux">
      {!!selected.length && <MyClearButton onClick={onClear} />}
      {!selected.length && isLoading && <MySpinner />}
    </div>
  )}
</Typeahead>
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rbt-custom-aux-components-gn3kn

Note that the `.rbt-aux` classname is used internally to position the built-in clear button and loader components and can be re-used. You may also add your own styles to position the custom components however you want.

Comment: Hi, I'm implementing Typeahead in React but when I set isLoading=true, then I always see that loader icon. I want to see that loader icon only when the user types something and not when he hasn't typed anything. How to achieve that? I also tried an alternative approach where I'm managing state based on data received and I'm comparing state to execute this:                                emptyLabel={this.state.isLoading ? "Searching..." : ''"}
           but this isn't working.

Comment: @ShridharK: Setting `isLoading=true` will always display the loader. Did you try passing `this.state.isLoading` instead?